# Generating package name attribute with nose coverage reports

Tags: python, jenkins, cobertura, nosetests, coverage.py

I'm configuring reports in Jenkins and

```
nosetests --with-xcoverage
```

gives me XML with an empty name attribute:

`<packages>
   <package branch-rate="0" complexity="0" line-rate="0.282" name="">`

which results in the coverage report looking a bit ugly:

[image]

I'd like to generate XML looking like:

```
<packages>
  <package name="src" line-rate="0.8125" branch-rate="0.7248">
```

Can't find anything in the coverage docs http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/config.html - can nose do this out of the box?

Comment: But your package name isn't "src", right?  You don't have lines like "import src" or "from src import thing", right?

Comment: @NedBatchelder - <package name="src"> was generated by another (JS) project using the Gulp for build

Comment: coverage.py uses actual Python package names in the <package> tag.  "src" is not a Python package name.  The Javascript conventions may be different, so other tools will do it differently.